# Struct layout: can't make a constructor to set the field I need

Tags: struct, lisp, common-lisp

The code below "compiles", but doesn't function properly:

```
(defstruct (image-info
             (:conc-name img-)
             (:constructor %make-img-info (&key file))
             (:print-function print-img-info))
  (file nil :type string)
  (gd-image nil :type (or cl-gd::image null))
  (size '(0 . 0) :type cons)
  (position '(0 . 0) :type cons))

(defun print-img-info (info stream level)
  (declare (ignore level))
  (let ((size (img-size info))
        (pos (img-position info)))
    (format stream "~s[width: ~d, height: ~d, x: ~d, y: ~d]"
            (img-file info)
            (car size) (cdr size) (car pos) (cdr pos))))

(defun make-img-info (path)
  (let ((image (cl-gd:create-image-from-file path))
        (info (%make-img-info :file path))) ; <--- problem here
    (setf (img-gd-image info) image
          (img-size info)
          (cons (cl-gd:image-width image)
                (cl-gd:image-height image))) info))
```

SBCL infers correctly the type of the argument to `%make-img-info`, as can be seen here:

```
(describe '%make-img-info)
SPRITESHEET::%MAKE-IMG-INFO
  [symbol]

%MAKE-IMG-INFO names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (&KEY (FILE NIL))
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (&KEY (:FILE STRING))
                  (VALUES IMAGE-INFO &OPTIONAL))
```

But when I try to compile the `make-img-info`, I get this:

```
  note: deleting unreachable code
  warning: 
    Derived type of PATH is
      (VALUES CL-GD::IMAGE &OPTIONAL),
    conflicting with its asserted type
      STRING.
```

I'm passing the correct argument (a string) to this function, but it still fails to call it because it "believes" that it has to be `cl-gd:image`. I suspect that the problem is that the layout is somehow alphabetical, and `gd-image` comes up before `file` in the list... but how do I then address this? I don't really want to rename the field?

Comment: I don't get any of your errors when I compile in sbcl 1.1.2. I don't have the GD library installed under the hood though.

Answer (score 0):

Now I believe this was some sort of a glitch related to SLIME and SBCL not cooperating very well when compiling structs. I cannot consistently reproduce this behaviour, but it happens now and then with other structs too so that some times I need to kill SLIME and SWANK, restart SBCL and recompile because recompiling only the related parts of the struct will not work.

I'm not deleting the question because if anyone will come across similar behaviour, maybe it will help to restart the Lisp, so this experience can be useful.